# ML methods for cold start - domain adaptation

Tags: domain-adaptation

**Imagine a scenario**: You work with credit card transactions and you use ML to assign probabilities to each transaction to be fraudulent or not. You operate in different countries and you have ML models for either each country separate or for some specific regional area.

**Problem: How would you approach the case if you are starting to operate in a new country?**

We deal with semi cold start and/or domain adaptation problem, meaning there is data from other countries but no data for the new country and we want to adapt to a new country

**My solution** would be to have a generalised not country specific model.

Are there any other solutions, or maybe researched done?

PS:

1. All existing countries were bootstrapped using 3rd party services and now it is not an option to use them again
2. Transfer learning would be not an option because I don't have data from the target domain.

Comment: This is interesting. May I ask what strategies you ended up using?

Answer (score 1):

Based on a similar problem in retail demand forecasting (my own domain) of how to forecast demand for new products or new stores that don't have any history to build a forecast from, I would use the following approach.

- Assume some measure of similarity of countries (do countries in the same region have similar models?) or see if there are any other groupings of the countries (based on demographics, economics indexes, etc...), calculate an "average model" for each group, and then see in which group does your new country fall.
- Create a bayesian model and use the average model of the group that the country belongs to as a bayesian prior, update your model as data from the new country comes in.

Comment: Both of the methods you suggested apply only when you have new country data in order to identify in which group it falls etc. I am at the point when I don't know have any datapoints, I have only prior knowledge that the new country *might* behave as the neighbour countries

Comment: @IrisPader I don't understand - unless you don't even know which country you are operating in - you must have some of the data required for step 1. When we forecast for new products we use some pretty superficial indicators for our similarity (brand, style, color, etc...)